# How to flip an mp4 video horizontally in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, moviepy

I have looked into this in moviepy and ffmpeg but could only find how to rotate a video, and not flip it horizontally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ffmpeg, its easy to flip a video horizontally:

```
import ffmpeg
stream = ffmpeg.input('input.mp4')
stream = ffmpeg.hflip(stream)
stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, 'output.mp4')
ffmpeg.run(stream)
```

Reference: [ffmpeg-python Github](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python)

Well, you haven't mentioned that you need to preserve the audio as well.
But, if you want to preserve audio in your clip you can do the following. Note, I have used moviepy library.

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, vfx
video = VideoFileClip('sample.mp4')
out = video.fx(vfx.mirror_x)
out.write_videofile('out.mp4')
```

Comment: This appears to get rid of all audio. Is there a solution that preserves the audio?

Comment: You should have specified that in your question. Well, I have edited my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: To be fair, with an mp4 video it should have gone without saying. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Since the question is tagged `moviepy`:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, vfx
clip = VideoFileClip('video.mp4')
reversed_clip = clip.fx(vfx.mirror_x)
reversed_clip.write_videofile('new_video.mp4')
```

See [this page](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videofx.html) for a general list of predefined effects.

Answer (score 0):

To complement [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48491282/8629311), the code below preserves the audio when flipping with `ffmpeg-python`:

```py
input_video = ffmpeg.input('input.mp4')
flipped_video = input_video.hflip()
audio = input_video.audio
out = ffmpeg.output(flipped_video, audio, 'output.mp4')
out.run()
```

If the video has no audio, you'll need to catch the exception.

Ref: https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/tree/master/examples#audiovideo-pipeline