# How to flip a video horizontally or vertically on command-line terminal with ffmpeg?

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg, computer-vision

Python solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48491070/how-to-flip-an-mp4-video-horizontally-in-python). But how to do it on command-line in terminal (without python dependency)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Horizontal flip:

```
ffmpeg -i input_video_file_path -vf hflip output_video_file_path
```

Vertical flip:

```
ffmpeg -i input_video_file_path -vf vflip output_video_file_path
```